# How to sum data custom week wise in sql 2012.(mon-sun,thu-mon...)

Tags: sql, grouping, weekday

I have a table with two columns.

```
pydt Decimal(13,0) and amt Decimal(18,4)
```

payDt column contains datetime in UNIX time stamp and amt contains amount.
Now i need to make a report week wise.For this i use bellow command.

### Command

```
Select X.PMonth,X.PWeek,SUM(X.Payment) as Payment from
(
    select 
      MONTH(dateadd(s,CAST(LEFT(pydt, LEN(pydt) - 3) AS DECIMAL(10,0)),'01/01/1970')) as PMonth,
      DATEPART(WK,dateadd(s,CAST(LEFT(pydt, LEN(pydt) - 3) AS DECIMAL(10,0)),'01/01/1970')) as PWeek,
      amt as Payment
    from tblpayment
)X
group by 
X.PMonth,X.PWeek
order by X.PMonth,X.PWeek
```

And it works.
Now i need to specify week start and week and for report.
Means i need a sql query that automatically sum data based on given week start and week end days.

### Ex.

```
Mon to Sun,Tue to Mon,........... and Sun to Mon
```

Can any one tell me how can i do that.

### Edit-2

### Ex.

```
DECLARE @TESTTABLE TABLE(pydt DECIMAL(13,0),amt DECIMAL(18,4))
INSERT INTO @TESTTABLE
SELECT 1371633942104,   500.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1371536351014,   200.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1371508936993,   800.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1371421684905,   800.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1371279960886,   500.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1371250768515,   900.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1371115833490,   200.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1371052445207,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370935778269,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370874220086,   200.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370790602634,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370679256936,   300.000 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1370644477888,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370524059728,   500.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370419275541,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370383832831,   900.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370299308283,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370211913979,   200.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370066810107,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1370039853256,   200.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369888990306,   200.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369864999229,   1000.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369863700412,   200.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369863257127,   300.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369863225725,   200.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369860049462,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369859952006,   -47.640 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369858718486,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369835887771,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369815058443,   100.000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1369781776403,   900.000 
Select min(X.pydt) as [Start From],max(X.pydt) as [End To],MAX(X.PMonth) AS PMonth,X.PWeek,SUM(X.Payment) as Payment from
(
  select 
  dateadd(s,CAST(LEFT(pydt, LEN(pydt) - 3) AS DECIMAL(10,0)),'01/01/1970') as pydt,
  MONTH(dateadd(s,CAST(LEFT(pydt, LEN(pydt) - 3) AS DECIMAL(10,0)),'01/01/1970')) as PMonth,
  DATEPART(WK,dateadd(s,CAST(LEFT(pydt, LEN(pydt) - 3) AS DECIMAL(10,0)),'01/01/1970')) as PWeek,
  amt as Payment
  from @TESTTABLE
)X
group by 
X.PWeek
order by PMonth,X.PWeek
```

### Result

```
Start From          End To               PMonth PWeek   Payment
2013-05-28 22:56:16 2013-06-01 06:06:50     6   22     3452.3600
2013-06-02 22:25:13 2013-06-08 08:14:16     6   23     2200.0000
2013-06-09 15:10:02 2013-06-15 07:06:00     6   24     2100.0000
2013-06-16 22:28:04 2013-06-19 09:25:42     6   25     2300.0000
```

Here result show grouped data from Sunday to Saturday.
Now i need group by data from specific day to day.

### Just like result shows data.

```
From 2013-06-02 22:25:13(Sunday) To 2013-06-08 08:14:16(Saturday)
```

### I need data

```
From 2013-06-04 22:25:13(Tuesday) To 2013-06-08 08:14:16(Monday)
```

I think every thing is clear.

Comment: You want a moving window of 7 days?

Comment: It may be 1 day 2 day and so on.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding your question correctly you can do this at the beginning of your code

```
set datefirst 2
```

That will make Tuesday the first day of your week.  This will also make Monday the last date of your week.

Comment: Thanks it works.But if we want grouped by data of 2 days,3 days or so on in that case what we can do.

Comment: if you're trying to keep the weeks together just case it out with dateparts(dw) then adding that with the date.  but you'll end up with 2-2-3 or 2-3-2, something like that.

I believe your question is more about ignoring the fact that weeks are a base unit, so you end up with tues,wed; thurs,fri; sat,sun; mon,tues; wed,thus; and so forth.  in this case, get your query to a point where each date appears once.  then query into that with row_number, group by row_number / 2 (or 3 if you wish) rounded down, take the min(date), sum(amount) 

this is the approach I would take, there may be easier way